# Timefold: the best way to create constraints for specific pairs of entities

Tags: java, constraints, optaplanner, timefold

I'm trying to use timefold in Graph Coloring problem.

And I'm wondering, what is the best way to create constraint "The Points on the same edge have different color".

Now I'm using this code:

```
constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Point.class)
                .filter(Point::isNeighbour)
                .penalizeConfigurable((p1, p2) -> p1.getColor() == p2.getColor()?1:0)
                .asConstraint(MainConstraintConfiguration.DIFFERENT_COLORS);
```

But there is a problem: "isNeighbour" is launching for every move, while it is enough to launch it only at the start.

I've also tried this code:

```
constraintFactory.forEach(PointPair.class)
                .penalizeConfigurable(pointPair -> pointPair.getPoint1().getColor() == pointPair.getPoint2().getColor()?1:0)
                .asConstraint(MainConstraintConfiguration.DIFFERENT_COLORS);
```

where:

```
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private List<PointPair> edges;
```

This code doesn't work at all. The score doesn't react to any move. I think it's reasonable because timefold doesn't understand, which points have influence on this constraint.

Any advice?

Comment: Looks like it was much better to put color checking inside forEachUniquePair like this: constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(Point.class, Joiners.equal(Point::getColor)). Still it isn't an answer for original question.

Answer (score 0):

If a Point looks like this:

```
class Point {
    Set<Point> neighbors;
    boolean isNeighbor(Point other) {neighbors.contains(other)}
    ...
}
```

such that the `Set<Point> neighbors` is precalculated before calling `solve()`, the code is probably fast enough, no?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this. Yes, for now the code is fast enough, but if there is a better way, I'd like to know.

Comment: If profiling flamegraphs show the hashcode lookup is too expensive in the Set (I doubt it until proven!), you could trade memory for performance by giving every Point an unique index (for a list of all points) and then have a List<Boolean> per Point. But premature optimization is the root of all evil...